# Self Join without double counting sales

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to create a market basket query. Table_data pulls in all the transactions for all items sharing a basket with the Host_Category (category 123 in this case); but the current SQL I am using is duplicating the sales of the attached items since I am doing a full join of the table to itself and sometimes there is more than 1 item of the host category in the same transaction (as shown in example below):

[image: Picture of example table and output]

How do I change my query to get the desired output?

My query is below:

```
SELECT Host_Category,Attached_Item
       ,Count(DISTINCT Trx_NBR || Location_NBR || Trx_Date) AS Shared_Trx_Count
       ,Sum(Host_Sales) AS Host_Sales
       ,Sum(Attached_Sales) AS Attached_Sales
FROM (SELECT a.Trx_NBR, a.Trx_Date, a.Location_NBR
             ,CASE WHEN a.Category IN (123) THEN '123' END AS Host_Category
             ,a.sales AS Host_Sales
             ,b.Item AS Attached_Item, b.sales AS Attached_Sales
      FROM table_data a FULL JOIN table_data b
      ON a.Trx_NBR = b.Trx_NBR AND a.Location_NBR = b.Location_NBR AND a.Trx_Date = b.Trx_Date
      WHERE a.Category IN (123) ) AS c GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Add the SQL db please

Comment: teradata sql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate *before* the join to get unique data. This might be what you want:

```
SELECT Host_Category,Attached_Item
       -- do you still need COUNT(DISTINCT)? Or is COUNT(*) ok?
       ,Count(DISTINCT Trx_NBR || Location_NBR || Trx_Date) AS Shared_Trx_Count
       ,Sum(Host_Sales) as Host_Sales
       ,Sum(Attached_Sales) AS Attached_Sales
FROM
 (
   SELECT a.*
         ,b.Item AS Attached_Item
         ,b.sales AS Attached_Sales
   FROM
    (
      SELECT a.Trx_NBR, a.Trx_Date, a.Location_NBR
          ,CASE WHEN a.Category IN (123) THEN '123' END AS Host_Category
          ,Sum(a.sales) AS Host_Sales
      FROM table_data AS a
      WHERE a.Category IN (123)
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    ) AS a
   -- your previous Full Join was a Left Join anyway due to the WHERE-condition
   LEFT JOIN table_data b
   ON a.Trx_NBR = b.Trx_NBR 
   AND a.Location_NBR = b.Location_NBR
   AND a.Trx_Date = b.Trx_Date
 ) AS c 
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: You can probably take away the outer nested query and group the join directly

Comment: @CR7SMS: That's right, of course. Btw, the optimizer will do it anyway :-)

Comment: I tried to use this query, but to get it to work I had to move ,Host_Sales before ,Count(DISTINCT Trx_NBR || Location_NBR || Trx_Date) AS Shared_Trx_Count and add a 3 to the group by clause since Host_sales is not an aggregation. After getting the query to work it gave me the right numbers for the attached_sales, but the Host_Sales are now missing sales (which they did not miss in my original query). Any idea why sales are missing from Host_Sales? In the meantime I will keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I just needed to add Sum() to Host_Sales and that caused both the Host and Attached Sales to be correct. Thank you so much dnoeth and CR7SMS!

Comment: Correct, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use min/max or some other aggregation function, instead of sum and that could do the trick:

```
SELECT Host_Category,Attached_Item
       ,Count(DISTINCT Trx_NBR || Location_NBR || Trx_Date) AS Shared_Trx_Count
       ,Sum(Host_Sales) AS Host_Sales
       ,min(Attached_Sales) AS Attached_Sales
FROM (SELECT a.Trx_NBR, a.Trx_Date, a.Location_NBR
             ,CASE WHEN a.Category IN (123) THEN '123' END AS Host_Category
             ,a.sales AS Host_Sales
             ,b.Item AS Attached_Item, b.sales AS Attached_Sales
      FROM table_data a FULL JOIN table_data b
      ON a.Trx_NBR = b.Trx_NBR AND a.Location_NBR = b.Location_NBR AND a.Trx_Date = b.Trx_Date
      WHERE a.Category IN (123) ) AS c GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: There are more transactions/date/location aka unique transactions than the one I listed in the table. So if I just do min, then I will only get the min value for the attached category for the unique transaction that happens to have the lowest value for the attached category. Is there a way for me to sum the min values of all unique transactions in this query?